# Excel Round individual values before they are summed in SUMIF formula

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, rounding, sumifs

I am working with a table in Excel 2010 and I need to be able to show a value in a column that shows the sum of a range for every value that meets two criteria. I also need it to round each value prior to summing. I've seen people use an array formula to round each value independently prior to summing, but I am not seeing how to do this with a sumifs statement.

My formula looks like this:

```
 =sumifs(pData[premium],pdata[Pol],[@[Pol]],pdata[LineNum],[@[LineNum]])
```

Now.. I don't want to round the sum of everything, I want everything rounded prior to summing. Essentially, for each value that meets the sumif criteria, it should be rounded up or down prior to summing.

`=Round(sumifs(pData[premium],pdata[Pol],[@[Pol]],pdata[LineNum],[@[LineNum]]),0)` sums the total and is generally off by a few numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a `SUMIF`, would this work for your situation? As @nutsch pointed out, this can be arranged as follows and it does not need to be entered as an array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$12="A")*($B$1:$B$12="B")*ROUND($C$1:$C$12,0))
```

This finds the value where column A = "A" and column B = "B", and then returns the rounded number in column C.

Comment: Easier syntax: `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$12="A")*($B$1:$B$12="B")*ROUND($C$1:$C$12,0))`

Comment: I plugged this in last week, but in doing so, ended up still getting different numbers than I expected. I knew the problem was with my data but wanted to adjust the data and then give this formula another shot to see if it worked. Worked perfectly :) Thanks @RocketDonkey

Comment: @AshtonSheets Awesome, great to hear!

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**
I prefer to use array formulas in this case:

```
=SUM(IF(pdata[Pol]=[@[Pol]],IF(pdata[LineNum]=[@[LineNum]],ROUND(pData[premium],1))))
```

then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: This won't work Gimp, SUMIFS only accepts ranges as sum-range (or criteria range). Modifying the range with a function, like ROUND, convert's it to an array, so you'll get an error.

Comment: Thanks berry, I was posting this quick before lunch and must not have been thinking straight! I modified my answer to be a true array formula with a `sum(if())`